# where is the form post url

Tags: html

I get the source codes of a web form in which use 'post' methos to upload files

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
```

there should be url after action=

but for this case is

```
action=""
```

where is the form post url?

Welcome any comment

Comment: I am unsure what you actually ask here. You are right that action should contain the URL that accepts your upload request. So do you ask what url to put in there? It's impossible to give an answer to that without more information.

Comment: Is it generated by JavaScript maybe?

Comment: no javascript codes on the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no action is given (should never be the case, but often is) the form will be submitted to the same page. If you have a script that handles uploads the action should be set to that url, such as `action="upload.php"`

Answer (score 0):

try wireshark:
http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

You will see the final request which is being sent by the website. Then you can do the same from your code. It always helps me a lot. Really useful tool.